# Xcode Cloud Build input file not found

Tags: xcode, xcode-cloud

I'm trying to get Xcode Cloud up and running for my project. I'm using the basic default workflow, but it is failing with the following error

`Build input cannot be found /GoogleService-Info.plist. Did you forget to declare this file as an output of a script phase or custom build rule which produces it`

I don't have any issues with distribution or building, just XCode Cloud.